# Woocommerce shows title of the first product instead of category title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the Avano theme (no support) and the category pages are not showing the category title. Instead, it shows the title from the first product in that category.

You can see an example in their own demo: http://ninethemes.net/avano/wordpress/1/product-category/music/

As you can see the category title is: Woo Album 1. This is not the category title (Music) but the first product in the category.

Really can't figure this out. Doe anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: may be there is an bug. You just customize the archive.php page and call the the_category() function where the_title fucniton called in it.

Comment: @HaninderSingh - you are correct

Comment: @sijovijayan add me on skype: harryr891

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Avano theme, They have not created a header-shop.php file in the root of the theme directory. I have fixed this issue in my own way.

1. Activate the child theme
2. Make a header-shop.php file in the child theme directory
3. Copy and paste the content of the header.php file of the parent theme ( Avano )
4. Replace the `h1` tage like the following

Use the following code

```
     <h1 id="title-page">
        <?php single_term_title(); ?>
     </h1>
```

Instead of the code below

```
   <h1 id="title-page">
      <?php the_title( ); ?> // Its a wrong code - Don't use
   </h1>
```